# Is there a way to find a specific word in a text file and know its seekg() position using fstream?

Tags: c++, fstream

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    ifstream infile("myfile.txt");
    string line, input;
    cout<<"Input the text u want to find"<<endl;
    cin>>input;
    infile.open();
    while(!infile.eof())
    { 
        while(getline(infile,line))
        {
            if(line==input)
            { 
                cout<<line<<endl; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I only know how to find a specific line in a text file and cout it, but i dunno how to cout the line above or below it.

example of my text file:

Mary 
 9am-11am 
 Benny 
 10am-12pm 
 Harry 
 9am-11am

example of my input:

9am-11am

what i wan to cout:

Mary
9am-11am
Harry
9am-11am

Comment: If your Text file always looks the same, you could just remember the last line.

Comment: file streams have `tellg` that gives the current position in the stream. This would, of course, be /after/ the line that has just been read. But then, it's just a matter of logic of figurig out the correct position. You have all the necessary information to do that.